# strSQL in Access VBA Won't Executre

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have the following code in Access VBA:

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim MaxOfMarkAsofDate As Date



CurveID = 15

MaxOfMarkAsofDate = #7/31/2015#


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & " ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"


Debug.Print strSQL

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print vbCrLf
    Debug.Print "First", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print "Last", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
    Debug.Print "There are " & rs.RecordCount & " records and " & rs.Fields.Count & " fields."

    Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double
    Dim I As Integer

    BucketTermAmt = 3
    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, MaxOfMarkAsofDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
    Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate




End If
End Sub
```

Originally, I only had one WHERE clause in the strSQL statement. Since adding a second condition (MaxOfMarkAsofDate = #7/31/2015#) the code no longer executes. As far as I can tell it should work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might try building the string with string parts. Change to `Dim MaxOfMarkAsofDate As String: MaxOfMarkAsofDate = "#7/31/2015#">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate, MaturityDate"
```

(so with # before and after the date)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I see what the error was from the debug print, I needed an exact match for the date.

Comment: Also, i dont think you need to order it by the date as you'll only have 1

Comment: That will only fix it in a US environment. Anywhere else, specifically format the date expression like: `.. MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & Format(MaxOfMarkAsofDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# ..`